# ReactJS axios POST request send all options as a single JSON key with empty value

Tags: php, reactjs, ionic-framework, axios, codeigniter-4

I am using ReactJS in the frontend and making a POST request to a CodeIgniter4 backend.

My frontend call looks like this -

```
axios.post('http://localhost/exampleApiEndpoint', { sample_key: 'sample_value' })
    .then(response => {
        // Do something
    })
```

If I run the following code -

```
$this->request->getPost('sample_key');
```

I expect it to return 'sample_value' but I get `null`

So I decided to run the following code in CI4 to see what is happening in the background

```
$this->request->getRawInput()
```

it returns `{{"hello":"world"}: ""}`

And sure enough when I run `$this->request->getPost('{"hello":"world"}');` it gives me empty string (no null, but empty string)

I am new to both frameworks. I am not entirely sure how to proceed further from this point.
I used the following snippet as a workaround which works as long as there are no symbols in the input. If there are any, they are converted to underscore. Which is less than ideal.

```
$raw_input = $this->request->getRawInput();
$json_input = json_decode(array_key_first($raw_input));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios sends the data in the format of JSON Body while sending the data to the API. In order for you to send the data as a POST, you have to use FormData API.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('sample_key','sample_value');
```

Than Send this FormData object instead of the Javascript Object that you are sending:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/exampleApiEndpoint', formData)
    .then(response => {
        // Do something
    })
```

In the CI4 Controller you can get your data by following :

```
$data = $this->request->getPost();
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works for me. Although I would still prefer sending data in json format. But this works just as well :)

Comment: Yeah, that is more convenient, but there is no way to post the data by passing JSON directly (as per my knowledge atleast).

Answer (score 0):

The [axios client is posting the request with `Content-Type` header of `application/json`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.20.0/lib/defaults.js#L50) and as a raw input stream of JSON payload.

Use [CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest::getJSON](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/v4.0.4/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L361) to grab this stream from the request body as parse it as `JSON` into an object.

```php
$json = $this->request->getJSON();

// Access sample_key field from object
$json->sample_key;
```

You could also parse the request body into an associative array by passing `true` for the first parameter.

```php
$json = $this->request->getJSON(true);

// Access 'sample_key' key in array
$json['sample_key'];
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Looks very elegant, but it doesn't work for me. ```$this->request->getJSON();``` returns null.

Comment: @AlienSteak It should return the payload posted. I took some time to [set up an experiment](https://github.com/osule/CI4)

Answer (score 0):

Make you data object in such a way & then pass this object to post request.

```
let data = {sample_key: "sample_value"}

axios.post('http://localhost/exampleApiEndpoint', data)
.then(response => {
    // Do something
})
```

Thanks